# Javascript not showing prompts

Tags: javascript, html

I made a JS code to protect a page, but it seems that it doesen't show any prompt. When I access the page, it shows the press me button and it can't be pressed. Please help me!

```
    <HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--hide
function passWord()
var password;

var pass1="zonaleo";

password= prompt('Parola te rog!',' ');

if (password==pass1)
  alert('Corect! Vei fi redirectionat catre lista membrilor!');
  window.location="membri\23ian.html"
else
   {
    window.location="papa.html"
    }

//-->
</SCRIPT>
<input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ancient version of JavaScript. You have a lot of issues:

You need to do the following:

1. Remove the `type` / `language` from the `<script>` tag.
2. Use `//` before the comment.
3. Open the `function ()` with `{` and close `}`.
4. Same goes for `if` statement.
5. Put the `<input />` tag inside the `<body>` and not inside `<head>`.

For upgrading to modern standards, kindly update your code like this:

```
//<!--hide
function passWord() {
  var password;

  var pass1="zonaleo";

  password= prompt('Parola te rog!',' ');

  if (password==pass1) {
    alert('Corect! Vei fi redirectionat catre lista membrilor!');
    window.location="membri\23ian.html"
  }
  else {
    window.location="papa.html"
  }
}

//-->
```

Comment: I tried your code, but when I enter the correct password it dosen't redirects me to membri\23ian.html

Comment: @PopentiuVlad Encapsulate `pass1` inside `"pass1"`.

Comment: `<SCRIPT>
  var password;

  var "pass1"="zonaleo";

  password= prompt('Parola te rog!',' ');

  if (password==pass1) {
    alert('Corect! Vei fi redirectionat catre lista membrilor!');
    window.location="membri\23ian.html"
  }
  else {
    window.location="papa.html"
  }
</SCRIPT>
`                           still not working

Comment: Sorry, change `var pass1="zonaleo";` - This should be.

Answer (score 0):

The input field should be out of the head tag and in the body

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shortened and working code

```
<script>
function passWord()
{
    if (prompt('Parola te rog!')=="zonaleo"){
    alert('Corect! Vei fi redirectionat catre lista membrilor!');
    window.location="membri\23ian.html"
  }
    else
  {
    window.location="papa.html"
  }
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onclick="passWord()">
```

Comment: When I enter the correct password, it redirects me to membri\13ian.html wich dosen't exists.

Comment: remove it, e.g line window.location="membri\23ian.html"